# foreach loop retriving and showing value of LAST STAR RATING

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this div where ratings are shown and the ratings are fetched from db and values are getting outputted But my Problem only the last star rating value of the userid is shown

View Page

```
<?php foreach($testi as $test){ ?>     
    <div class="form-group">
       <fieldset class="rating">
            <legend>Ratings Given:</legend>
            <input type="radio" id="star5" name="hel_banners[rating]" disabled="true" value="5"<?php if($test->rating == 5) echo'checked'; ?> /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star4" name="hel_banners[rating]" disabled="true" value="4"<?php if($test->rating == 4) echo'checked'; ?> /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star3" name="hel_banners[rating]" disabled="true" value="3"<?php if($test->rating == 3) echo'checked'; ?> /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star2" name="hel_banners[rating]" disabled="true" value="2"<?php if($test->rating == 2) echo'checked'; ?> /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star1" name="hel_banners[rating]" disabled="true" value="1"<?php if($test->rating == 1) echo'checked'; ?> /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
        </fieldset>               
    </div>
<?php  }    ?>
```

Controller:

```
 public function index(){
       $data['title'] = "HR & Employee Engagement Testimonials"; 
       $data['descriptions'] = 'Check our website to learn what others say about us.';
       $data['testi'] = $this->Home_model->GettestimonialApprove();
        load_view_frond_template('home/testimonials',$data,$this);
        $this->template->render();
    }
```

Model:

```
public function GettestimonialApprove(){
        $where = "categoryid ='7' AND act = '1' ";
        $this->db->select("*")->from('hel_banners')->where($where)->order_by('bId', 'asc');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: Could you post `var_dump($test)` output? And I don't see that you've closed with `}` your `foreach` loop after `</div>`

Comment: ["bannersPhoto"]=> string(10) "images.png" ["customerPhoto"]=> string(6) "18.png" ["rating"]=> string(1) "2" ["status"]=> string(1) "1" ["created_date"]=> string(19) "2018-10-26 00:00:00" ["created_by_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["created_by_role"]=> string(4) "User" ["updated_date"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["updated_by_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["updated_by_role"]=> string(0) "" ["act"]=> string(1) "1" } For the Last loop User

Comment: ["rating"]=> string(1) "2"  for first user

Comment: Dimitrov i did close wait ill show my full post

Comment: INSTEAD OF `$testi` USE `$data['testi']` in your foreach

Comment: @AlivetoDie check now my controller no need to use $data['testi']

Comment: @AmalJoseph  i have checked it and still my comment is same. from where `$testi` is coming?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Hey its codeigniter structure you can assign an value and retrive it in View page .i have given testi as the variable that fetches data from the DB

Comment: what does "only the last star rating value of the userid is shown" mean, specifically? what is your desired output

Comment: @Alex consider there are 5 users and they each given an rating and i want to show each users rating but my output is only showing 5th user's star rating

Comment: i see, i don't see anything wrong really. perhaps there is only 1 entry given your where conditions. you can confirm this by `print_r($data['testi'])` in controller